# Traverse (Read) static DOM document object is thread-safe or not?

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing, thread-safety

I created a DOM document static object, such as below, it uses javax.xml.parsers.* and org.w3c.dom.* API:

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBldrFactry = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docBldrObj = docBldrFactry.newDocumentBuilder();

        File file = new File(fileDirectory);
        // Parse the XML file and return a DOM document object

        document = docBldrObj.parse(file);
        //FYI, document is declared as private static org.w3c.dom.Document document elsewhere.
```

Later after created above, If this static DOM document object shared by threads, but all threads are just read (traverse) this document, is it thread safe?

I assume it is since read should not modify this shared state, but not sure whether internally there is some magic about it which I don't know.

Thanks

Comment: Damm... As I tried, it seems not.. Some APIs which seem readonly (such as getNodeValue()) modify the state.

Comment: Does anyone know any thread-safe XML libs if I ONLY read (traverse) the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved by writing own simple Document structure. E.g, clone the DOM document into that, which is thread-safe on read operations.
FYI, for my own purpose, when cloning the document, I don't clone everything but the information based on my need (COMMENT_NODE, TEXT_NODE, ELEMENT_NODE, attributes).